# Can't explode string on end of line PHP

Tags: php, string, rss

I'm writing a PHP app to take data from an RSS feed and store it ready to serve in a different format for a mobile app.

Everything's working ok, apart from the important bit that takes the data from a string. There are clearly new lines in the data, but I can't explode it! Here's my attempt so far in trying to store each line into an array. I've exhausted my knowledge and Google's results!!

```
    // Prepare the data
    $possibleLineEnds = array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r");
    $preparedData = trim($row['description']);

    // Loop through and replace the data
    foreach ($possibleLineEnds as $lineEnd) {

      $preparedData = str_replace($lineEnd, "\n", $preparedData);
    }

    // Explode the data into new rows
    $locationData = explode("\n", $preparedData);

    print_r($locationData);
```

Any ideas, anything at all would be welcomed on this!

---

I can't mark this as answered because I don't have a rating of 10.

I've got it working! I know its not as neat as it could be, I plain don't understand patterns for the preg functions!

Here's the code that worked:

```
    // Prepare the data
    $possibleLineEnds = array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "<br>", "<br/>", "&lt;br/&gt;");
    $preparedData = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($row['description']));

    // Replace the possible line ends
    $preparedData = str_replace($possibleLineEnds, "\n", $preparedData);

    // Explode the data into new rows
    $locationData = explode("\n", $preparedData);

    print_r($locationData);
```

Thanks for everyone's input, we got there in the end!

Comment: I think you should add some content .. because it's like a needle in a haystack.

Comment: besides the redundant foreach loop: str_replace() can take array arguments

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it. Are you processing that RSS link? There're cases where explode() is more efficient (cost-benefit wise), but parsing RSS is not one of them.

Comment: Yes, I'm processing the data from that RSS link. The data is inconsistent from it, but its the only UK tide data I can find. the UK government data supply is way too expensive!

Answer (score 1):

I would just use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to match any combination of `\n` and `\r` characters, rather than messing with the string using `str_replace()` just so we can `explode()` it.

Your entire code is reduced to a single line:

```
$output = preg_split('/(\n|\r)+/', $input);
```

The only difference between this and your original solution is that if the input contains blank lines, they won't appear in the exploded output. But I think that's probably a good thing in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If You can't split by new line. Split by unique string;

```
// Prepare the data
$possibleLineEnds = array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "\n");
$preparedData = trim($row['description']);

// Loop through and replace the data
foreach ($possibleLineEnds as $lineEnd) {

  $preparedData = str_replace($lineEnd, ":::", $preparedData);
}

// Explode the data into new rows
$locationData = explode(":::", $preparedData);

print_r($locationData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working! I know its not as neat as it could be, I plain don't understand patterns for the preg functions!

Here's the code that worked:

```
// Prepare the data
$possibleLineEnds = array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "<br>", "<br/>", "&lt;br/&gt;");
$preparedData = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($row['description']));

// Replace the possible line ends
$preparedData = str_replace($possibleLineEnds, "\n", $preparedData);

// Explode the data into new rows
$locationData = explode("\n", $preparedData);

print_r($locationData);
```

Thanks for everyone's input, we got there in the end!

Answer (score 0):

What I usually use is:

```
$preparedData = str_replace("\r", "", $preparedData);
$locationData = explode("\n", $preparedData);
```

and this worked for me all the time, I hope it helps you out

Comment: This solution won't recognize old Macintosh line endings `\r`